# Probability of a row in a permutation matrix being "correct"

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, random-matrices, permutation-matrices

**Question:** We have a uniformly sampled permutation matrix $\Pi\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$. What is the probability that the $i$th row in $\Pi$ is in the "correct" position, which means that the $i$th row of $\Pi$ is equal to the $i$th row of an identity matrix $I$ with the same dimension as $\Pi$. For example, the 2nd row in the following permutation matrix is correct:
$$
\Pi=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

**My attempt:** If the matrix had no constraints on the row weight and column weight being one, then the answer would simply be $1/n$. However, the presence of the constrains of a permutation matrix makes this tricky. We can instead calculate this differently: Let us think of the random permutation matrix being generated in a random row-by-row fashion, starting with row $i$. Then the number of matrices with row $i$ being "correct" is
$$
1\cdot{n-1\choose 1}\dots{1\choose 1}=(n-1)!,
$$
and the total number of matrices is
$$
{n\choose 1}{n-1\choose 1}\dots{1\choose 1}=n!.
$$
Hence, the probability of row $i$ being correct is
$$
\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}=\frac{1}{n},
$$
which surprisingly is the same as our naive calculation... Is this correct? Thanks.